# Horizontal scroll inside a bootstrap panel body that contains list of panels

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a panel that contains a single row of child panels. I'm using AngularJS to dynamically create child panels and sometimes it causes overflow. I want to create a side scrollbar so that I can view all my panels in a single row.

I tried adding `style="white-space: nowrap; height: 100px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;"` on the parent panel-body. This creates the background element for horizontal sidebar but the actual scroll is missing. This normally works when the child elements are not list of panels but some other elements like `<h1>` or buttons.

I created jsfiddle for demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15681/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `display` property of the repeated div in ng-repeat to `inline-block`, to get them to display side by side. See the attached fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xsfdzadm/

Answer (score 1):

On your `data-ng-repeat` element you need to add the styling `display: inline-block;`. And if you want to keep the `col-md-2` width at higher screen sizes you will need to remove the float `float: none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15682/